# How do you add weekly, monthly, and yearly intervals to a date in a loop?

Tags: swift, date, for-loop, realm

I am appending items to an array with a for loop to add to Realm.

```
var transactionArray:[Transaction] = []

for _ in 1...numberOfTransactionsToAdd {

            let addedTransaction = Transaction()
            
            addedTransaction.transactionAmount = amount
            addedTransaction.transactionName = name
            addedTransaction.transactionDescription = desc
            addedTransaction.transactionDate = datePicked
            addedTransaction.transactionCategory = category

            transactionArray.append(addedTransaction)
        }

let transactionList = List<Transaction>()
        
        
        for transaction in transactionArray {
            
            transactionList.append(transaction)
            
        }
        
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(transactionList)
        }
```

This code works perfectly, but it saves all of the transactions on the same date.

I need to make them recurring transactions by adding weekly and monthly time intervals to the date.

I've tried creating a nested for loop to add date components:

```
for _ in 0...1 {
                datePicked = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: timeComponent, to: datePicked)!
            }
```

And I've tried adding time for weeks, but this will not work for months:

```
for _ in 0...7 {
                datePicked = datePicked + 24*60*60
            }
```

How do I append these addedTransaction objects with weekly and monthly intervals?

Comment: How do you know what to increase the date with?

Comment: The question is pretty vague since we don't know how amount, name, datePicked etc is populated. That being said, this code, as is, will create a bunch of duplicate Transaction() objects with all of their properties being identical. That's probably not what you want but maybe it is? Can you clarify? Also, we don't know what you want to do with the datePicked property. What is a *weekly and monthly interval*? How would a single property be an *and* e.g. a single property hold both a weekly AND a monthly interval?

Comment: @Joakim, this is my first app and I've been struggling with how to implement this functionality. I want the user to be able to save a transaction and have it repeat however they choose. If they get paid every 2 weeks or the 1st and 15th they should be able to make that happen without having to do it manually 100 times. Something similar to [TBRepeatPicker]: https://cocoapods.org/pods/TBRepeatPicker

Comment: @Jay each transaction should have a unique date. Example: the user has a cell phone charge on their account June 12, July 12, August 12... And have that repeat for 10 years or something. Everything else about the transaction (category, amount, name) is the same except for the date. I like TBRepeatPicker on Cocoapods, but I can't install the Swift 4 version. I just started coding a few months ago, and I've been trying to figure out how to add this feature.

Comment: I am not sure where the difficulty is exactly. When the user picks Jun 12, repeating monthly for one year, create 12 transactions with the associated date 6/6/12 7/6/12 etc. Does that work?

Comment: @Jay the difficulty is that I'm very green and for loops are still hard for me to grasp. I've never written a single line of code until a few months ago. I found a solution and posted the answer on this page. Not sure if that's the best way, but it will work for now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an existing answer but it relies on a third party module, which isn't a bad thing but if it were to not be updated in the future, it would invalidate the answer. Additionally, the objects in use are not clearly defined.

TL;DR - there's no need for a list or an array. Write the transactions as they are created and populated.

Detail:

So here's a more complete Swift answer, starting with the TransactionClass Realm object that has a convenience init for the date of the transaction as well as a primary key which is generally a good idea to have on objects.

```
class TransactionClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var transaction_id = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var date_picked = Date()
    convenience init(theDate: Date) {
        self.init()
        self.date_picked = theDate
    }
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "transaction_id"
    }
}
```

Then a function that creates a number of recurring transactions based on the pickedDate

```
let datePicked = Date() //using today as an example, insert your date here
let numMonths = 12 //recurring for 12 months
var dateComponent = DateComponents()

for index in 0..<numMonths {
    dateComponent.month = index
    if let futureDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponent, to: datePicked) {
        let t = TransactionClass(theDate: futureDate)
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(t)
        }
    }
}
```

and the output when printed

```
2020-07-12 13:30:32 +0000
2020-08-12 13:30:32 +0000
2020-09-12 13:30:32 +0000
2020-10-12 13:30:32 +0000
2020-11-12 14:30:32 +0000
2020-12-12 14:30:32 +0000
2021-01-12 14:30:32 +0000
2021-02-12 14:30:32 +0000
2021-03-12 14:30:32 +0000
2021-04-12 13:30:32 +0000
2021-05-12 13:30:32 +0000
2021-06-12 13:30:32 +0000
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you can try this:

```
for _ in 1...numberOfTransactionsToAdd {
    let addedTransaction = Transaction()

    addedTransaction.transactionAmount = amount
    addedTransaction.transactionName = name
    addedTransaction.transactionDescription = desc
    addedTransaction.transactionCategory = category
    
    // specify your date components (add month, day, whatever you need)
    var dateComponent = DateComponents() 
    dateComponent.day = 1
    dateComponent.month = 2
    // add the date components to `datePicked`
    let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponent, to: datePicked)!
    // set `transactionDate` to your new date
    addedTransaction.transactionDate = newDate

    transactionArray.append(addedTransaction)
}
```

Comment: This is very close. But it just sets all of the transactions to the newDate. Maybe I need to implement another for loop? I'm working on a solution...

Comment: @BriScoLeg You didn't mention *how* do you want to do it. To help you we need more information. If you just want to increase every date by 1 day (or by some constant interval) you can add the `index` parameter to the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this dilemma:

I used SwiftDate https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftDate to make it easier to work with dates.

I added a month to datePicked at the end of the loop, after transactionArray.append. This way, the first transaction date is on the date picked.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
func saveMultipleTransactions() {
        
        var transactionArray:[Transaction] = []
        
        let numberOfTransactionsToAdd = 12
        
        for _ in 1...numberOfTransactionsToAdd {
            
            let addedTransaction = Transaction()
                        
            addedTransaction.transactionAmount = amount
            addedTransaction.transactionName = name
            addedTransaction.transactionDescription = desc
            addedTransaction.transactionDate = datePicked
            addedTransaction.transactionCategory = category
            
            transactionArray.append(addedTransaction)
            
            datePicked = datePicked + 1.months
            
        }
        
        let transactionList = List<Transaction>()
        
        
        for transaction in transactionArray {
            
            transactionList.append(transaction)
            
        }
        
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(transactionList)
        }
    }
```

I plan to expand the functionality to make it more versatile, but this is what worked for me (for now).

Comment: We don't know what kind of var `datePicked` is. It's great it working for you but it will be unhelpful to others without more information. Can you update to make it more complete? Including your Realm object would be great.